# What is the flavor quality that makes cheese "sharp"? Are there other seasonings or foods with this "sharp flavor?

Tags: flavor, cheese, ingredient-selection

I love the flavor of sharp cheese (especially cheddar) and was wondering what exactly it is that makes aged cheese taste sharper. I was also wondering if there are any ingredients that emulate this sharp flavor.

Comment: "Sharp" in the sense of cheese is an Americanism, and I think the language affects the perception.

Comment: Possibly but there is a definite flavor difference between cheeses described as mild vs sharp. And it differs from how other foods change their taste as they age. I feel like many cheeses get smoother as they age even if their flavor is stronger. But cheddar definitely gets tangier as it ages.

Comment: It might be [histamine](https://www.cheesescience.org/histamine.html)

Answer (score 7):

The term/process you are looking for is acidity or acidification.  During the cheese making process lactose is broken down into lactic acid.  This lowers the pH and creates the tart, sour, or acidic taste you are referring to. Higher acid cheeses (lower pH) present as "sharper", an old cheddar, for example.  Ever have a salt and vinegar potato chip?  I get a similar flavor perception (minus the lactic, cheese flavors of course).  So, other acidic ingredients (vinegar, lemon) can easily get you in the same flavor perception ball park.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are referring to the umami flavor.

Per cooks illustrated:

> There’s more than one reason that classic combinations like a burger
> and cheddar cheese or the Parmesan cheese and anchovies in a Caesar
> salad taste so good: Not only do such ingredients simply go well
> together but it turns out that they contain complementary umami
> boosters that magnify flavor by as much as thirtyfold. More and more
> food scientists are concluding that when ingredients rich in naturally
> occurring glutamates are paired with ingredients that contain either
> one of the nucleotides inosinate or guanylate, the perception of
> umami, or savoriness, is dramatically

### Rich In Glutamates

(MG/100 G)

- Parmesan cheese  1,200-1,600
- Fish Sauce   950-1,383
- Soy sauce    800-1,300
- Tomato paste 680
- Cured ham    337
- Anchovies/sardines   280
- Beef 107
- Cheddar cheese   78
- Worcestershire sauce 34

### Rich In Nucleotides

(MG/100 G)

- Anchovies/sardines   193 (inosinate)
- Dried shiitake mushrooms 150 (guanylate)
- Pork 122 (inosinate)
- Beef 107 (inosinate)
- Dried porcini mushrooms  10 (guanylate)

Comment: It's possible that cheddar has more umami as it ages but this isn't the flavor I'm referring to. Parmigiano is a good example of a cheese with a lot of umami. The taste I'm talking about seems unique to a subset of cheeses including cheddar. It may be less true for non-American cheddar, but aged American cheddar has a sort of aggressive flavor. It's hard to describe which is why I asked the question.

Comment: I don't find umami flavors to be sharp or acidic at all.  The  characteristics the OP is describing are usually associated with the flavor "sour".

Comment: Ok gotchya. Understood.